# portforwarding/expose port for service rabbitmq on cloudfoundry

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud

I have a **rabbitmq as a service instance** on **CloudFoundry** and I want to create **portforwarding** for **rabbitmq service** in order to connect at **port 5672** from my **localhost** and also to read queues messages via API but on their website is a little procedure, but is a little bit tricky

**I created service-key for the service rabbitmq**

I tried to run :

```
$ cf ssh -L 445672:rabbitmq.rabbitmq.svc:5672 YOUR-HOST-APP  ### but who is this "host-app" ?
```

I don't have any "**rabbitmq**" application, my **rabbitmq** is installed as service and not as a application